GitHub page 'Your connection is not private' when using www
I have a godaddy domain www.mikaelcedergren.com, and its set up through Github pages. If I go to the link mikaelcedergren.com it works fine, but using www it results in 'Your connection is not private'.
Anyone knows what's wrong?

When you visit https://www.mikaelcedergren.com/, the server responds with a redirect to https://mikaelcedergren.com/ but the certificate sent by the server is for *.github.io and not for mikaelcedergren.com or *.mikaelcedergren.com.  Therefore, user-agents refuse to follow the redirect.  If there is a fix for the problem it must be done in GitHub Pages but unfortunately I don't know how.

in the DNS settings I needed to set a CNAME for 'www' that doesn't redirect to my domain, but instead my github pages address. Then in settings in github make sure to wait until a certificate has been created and then force https connection.
